# JavaScript Calculate array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have some struggles calculating inside a for each function with JavaScript.
I have one array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "attribute_operator": "*",
        "attribute_value_price": 3
    },
    {
        "attribute_operator": "+",
        "attribute_value_price": 2
    },
    {
        "attribute_operator": "*",
        "attribute_value_price": 2
    }
]
```

As you see, every value has operator, and there is a starting price, so the real calculation should look like (if starting price is 6 for example):

> 6 * 3 + 2 * 2

So the output should be in that case 40.

I know how to do it for sum, but how to implement my operator easily?

tried like:

```
let total = starting_price.value

        calculate_objects.forEach((a: { attribute_value_price: number; }) => {
          total += a.attribute_value_price;
        });

        console.log(total);
```

Comment: You'll need to parse the operator string and determine which mathematical operation to perform.

Comment: Not to nitpick, since the use case is unknown, but the answer to 6 * 3 + 2 * 2 is 22 (18 + 4). The order of operation follows [PEMDAS](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-pemdas.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is a good case for reduce. The starting value is that `starting_price`, and each turn of the loop applies a little function related to the operand...

```js
const starting_price = 6;
const operations = [{
    "attribute_operator": "*",
    "attribute_value_price": 3
  },
  {
    "attribute_operator": "+",
    "attribute_value_price": 2
  },
  {
    "attribute_operator": "*",
    "attribute_value_price": 2
  }
];

const operators = {
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
};

const result = operations.reduce((acc, el) => {
  let operator = operators[el.attribute_operator];
  let operand = el.attribute_value_price;
  return operator(acc, operand);
}, starting_price);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is a great answer, it surely allows to create custom operations also.

Answer (score -1):

You can use string literal with eval function. eval function is useful when you want to calculate an expression.

```
const obj = [
    {
        "attribute_operator": "*",
        "attribute_value_price": 3
    },
    {
        "attribute_operator": "+",
        "attribute_value_price": 2
    },
    {
        "attribute_operator": "*",
        "attribute_value_price": 2
    }
]
let starting_price = 6;
let total = starting_price;

obj.forEach((a) => {
    total =eval(`${total}${a.attribute_operator}${a.attribute_value_price}`) ;
});

console.log(total);
```

Warning:
Executing JavaScript from a string is an BIG security risk.

With `eval()`, malicious code can run inside your application without permission.

With `eval()`, third-party code can see the scope of your application, whitch can lead to possible attacks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This might be an optimal solution, but the answer from @danh is much more clear, and easy for custom implementation